# VB.NET Class Does Not Update my Variables

Tags: vb.net, class, basic

I Have two class.

1-) NumberClass
2-) MessageClass

Number Class ;

```
Public Class NumberClass

Property Number As Byte
End Class
```

Message Class;

```
Public Class MessageManager
Inherits NumberClass

Public Sub sendMessage()
    MsgBox(Number)
End Sub
End Class
Public Class Form1
```

This is my buttons code :

```
Private Sub ShowNumberBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowNumberBtn.Click
    Dim messageManager As New MessageManager
    messageManager.sendMessage()
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeNumberBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChangeNumberBtn.Click
    Dim numberClass As New NumberClass
    numberClass.Number = 50
    MsgBox("Number Changed to : " & numberClass.Number)
End Sub
```

Firstly i click Change Number Button. It changes Number Variable value to 50.
Everything is ok until here but when i click the send message button message shows old value of Number variable, it is not reflected in the sendMessage method.

Comment: You should include the code that shows your problem.

Comment: okey i added more information of my problem by the way sorry for my english

Comment: In other words, show us where you create an instance of those classes with the "New" keyword, are updating the values, and then attempting to display the values (thus showing it "hasn't changed").  Your last edit does none of that.

Comment: Okey i added my buttons code

Comment: Your button click handlers are creating two COMPLETELY SEPARATE instances of the class.  Of course the value is "not updated".  If you want the two button click handlers to act on the same instance of the class, then move the declaration out to FORM level so both handlers can access the same instance.

Comment: I already tried it. İs form level down of Public class form1? If so i already tried it but it not worked. Number variable value unchanged. But i tried to put new keyword to down of public class form 1 am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly fine for me...not sure what you tried as you never updated your code to show your attempts:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private messageManager As New MessageManager

    Private Sub ShowNumberBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowNumberBtn.Click
        messageManager.sendMessage()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangeNumberBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChangeNumberBtn.Click
        messageManager.Number = 50
        MsgBox("Number Changed to : " & messageManager.Number)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class NumberClass

    Property Number As Byte

End Class

Public Class MessageManager
    Inherits NumberClass

    Public Sub sendMessage()
        MessageBox.Show("Number = " & Number)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hey it worked bu i dont understand what different now ? really thanks by the way

Comment: Hey pls say me how it works on that code but dont works in my code everything is same i dont know whats wrong on me ? plss

Comment: Something must be different!  UPDATE your code in our original post above with your current attempt that doesn't work so we can help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I already tried it but i cant see any differance. I thinking am i stupid :(